# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column is of type bit but expression is of type integer

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert a BIT value in my postgres column called `isFile`. The following error is raised when passing IsFile=1

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column "IsFile" is of type bit but expression is of type integer
```

For some reason it's not type casting it to BIT type (unlike other DBAPIs)

I tried to pass a BIT object instead of `1`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BIT
IsFile=BIT(1)
```

which fails with:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'BIT'
```

Comment: Try `IsFile='1'`.

Comment: I'm thinking `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BIT` is for defining a `bit` column in a model.  If you look at the signature here [BIT](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.BIT) it is `length=None, varying=False`. This corresponds to `bit(n)` or `bit varying(n)`. In Postgres [bit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-bit.html)  is  a string type hence my previous comment. A quick test showed `psycopg2` adapts a string to a `bit` field.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, it works. This should an answer.